# Get JsonArray String values from HashMap <String , String>

Tags: java, arrays, json, hashmap

I have a `HashMap` like so

```
Map<String , String>
```

when I get an element from the map by key it returns

`["6"]` I need only the `6` , not `["6"]`

The value is added like so

```
map.put(k , jsonarray.toString()) ;
```

Thanks

Comment: also the value could contain many ["2" , "4" , "1"] ect

Comment: Could you also post `jsonarray.toString()` sample ?

Comment: What is expected output in case the value for a certain key is ["2", "4", "1"]?

Comment: the 2 , 4 ,1 are dataset id's these datasets names would be placed in a list and returned to the caller

Comment: @YarpoleCosgrave consider commenting to posted answers to know whether your problem was resolved or not.

Comment: Sorry the changes required effect a large number of classes , and then test cases to verify behavior takes time to implement.I have selected @ J.N 's response as the answer.As passing the JsonArray(in this case) Implicitly brings json parsing out of the parsing layer in to a transport layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you have 2 options change your map to

```
Map<String,Integer>
```

and then you'll need to put an int value inside

or when getting the value use:

```
Integer.valueOf(map.get("key"));
```

thats only valid in case your String inside the json is only an int - our you will get an exception!

Comment: I feel chaning the map would be best.

Comment: is it possible to put a json array there as in Interger ?

Comment: Youll have to parse it first before u put it inside the map

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Integer#parseInt(String)` to convert a `String` to an `Integer`

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(map.get("key"));
```

Comment: This approach does not work.Unless you parse the string first. on first pass the [ is evaluated and returns an error as [ in not an integer ,  same for "  .. as highlighted by @J. N

Answer (score 0):

You get only what you actually put in as value in the Map. So instead of using toString() while storing, you could put in the just the value which is 6 and for the multiple values you could put in an array of integer values.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Map` to `String` and `JsonArray` and store `JsonArray` directly instead of converting it to `String`

```
 Map<String , JsonArray>
```

Using your `Map` key, iterate your `JsonArray` object

```
JsonArray jsonArray;
Iterator<JsonElement> it = jsonArray.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

Comment: I think in most cases this would be the one of the best answers, But for my use case it moves json parsing from the parsing layer to the transport layer